# ParallelSum faster... if I don't load my own Package

Tags: parallelization, summation

I have a big sum to compute.

I remarked that if I load my package, the parallelisation is as slow as the "non" parallelisation. Whereas, when I don't load it, the parallelisation is faster.

The details about the package are listed at the end of this post

Here is my code.

```
Off[SixJSymbol::tri];    
d[j_]:=2*j+1;
Cj[k_] := (k*(k + 1));
(* << fonctionsGenerales`; When I uncomment this : the parallel sum is much slower*)
fctSommeCk4Ck5[k4_, k5_, k6_] := (-1)^(
   j1 + j2 + j3 + j4 + j5 + j6 + k4 + k5 + k6 + J) d[k4] d[k5] d[k6]*
   Cj[k4] Cj[k5] SixJSymbol[{k4, j4, J}, {j6, k6, j2}]*
   SixJSymbol[{k5, j5, J}, {j4, k4, j3}]*
   SixJSymbol[{k6, j6, J}, {j5, k5, j1}]*
   SixJSymbol[{j1, j2, j3}, {k4, k5, k6}];

{j1, j2, j3, j4, j5, j6, J}={14, 15, 29, 9, 38, 24, 8};

    ParallelSum[
 fctSommeCk4Ck5[k4, k5, k6], {k5, Abs[j5 - J], J + j5, 1}, {k6, 
  Abs[j6 - J], J + j6, 1}, {k4, Abs[j4 - J], J + j4, 1}];

Sum[fctSommeCk4Ck5[k4, k5, k6], {k5, Abs[j5 - J], J + j5, 1}, {k6, 
  Abs[j6 - J], J + j6, 1}, {k4, Abs[j4 - J], J + j4, 1}];
```

The ParallelSum takes approximately half time than the Sum to compute.

When I load my package which contains ~ 20 functions, the ParallelSum is then much slower than without it : it takes the same amount of time than the "regular" Sum.

I can display the functions in my Package if necessary but as the file is a little long I don't show it now, maybe someone will have an idea about this problem ?

Extra infos :

- When I load the package I have the message "Launching 4 local Kernel" as if I don't load the package.
- The package doesn't contains function which are needed in the
  ParallelSum (it doesn't contain Cj[k_], d[j_] or fctSommeCk4Ck5)
- When the ParallelSum is faster (so when the package is not loaded), the ParallelSum doesn't consider the Off[SixJSymbol::tri]; command which prevent to display warnings. But when it is not faster, it considers this command. I think it is an important remark to understand what is happening.

To say the last point in other term, I have these warnings when the package is not loaded (when the parallelisation is faster):
[image]

But as I have put at the beginning of the notebook the command `Off[SixJSymbol::tri];`, the notebook should'nt display it !

---

My package file is available here : https://ufile.io/n7p1a
The functions inside it are the following :

```
InegTrig[x_,y_,z_];
SystEq[j1_,j2_,j3_,j4_,j5_,j6_];
indicesSommation[conditionTriangulaire_,k4_,k5_,k6_,nbInstance_];
Generer6j[jmin_,jmax_];
alphaMoins[j1_,j2_,j3_,j4_,j5_,j6_];
alphaPlus[j1_,j2_,j3_,j4_,j5_,j6_];
alpha0[j1_,j2_,j3_,j4_,j5_,j6_];
triple456[j1_,j2_,j3_,j4_,j5_,j6_];
VolumeTetraedre[j1_,j2_,j3_,j4_,j5_,j6_];
triple456Square[j1_,j2_,j3_,j4_,j5_,j6_];
coeffMoins2[j1_,j2_,j3_,j4_,j5_,j6_];
coeffPlus2[j1_,j2_,j3_,j4_,j5_,j6_];
coeff0[j1_,j2_,j3_,j4_,j5_,j6_];
triple456SquareEtera[j1_,j2_,j3_,j4_,j5_,j6_];
opVolume[j1_,j2_,j3_,j4_,j5_,j6_];
qNombre[n_,q_];
qFactoriel[n_,q_];
qDelta[a_,b_,c_,q_];
SixJSymbolqDef[{j1_,j2_,j3_},{j4_,j5_,j6_},q_];
SixJSymbolEtendue[{j1_,j2_,j3_},{j4_,j5_,j6_}];
dq[J_,q_];
AnglesDiedraux[j1_,j2_,j3_,j4_,j5_,j6_];
AireTriangle[a_,b_,c_];
FirstDerivative[j1_,j2_,j3_,j4_,j5_,j6_];
```

Comment: At the very least please list which functions are defined in your package. As it is, we can do no more than guess at the problem.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to attach a file on the topic ? Cause the file is a little long to write directly

Comment: @MarcoB the file is available here : https://ufile.io/n7p1a

Comment: Thank you for sharing the file. Could you also add a list of the functions defined in the file (even without their definitions)?

Comment: @MarcoB I edited !